# Dificuldade para Criar um Parser Variável Simples Para AltoRouter

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Fiz um Simples Check de Váriavel PHP, porém ele foi desenvolvido em Base de Mysqli, o fato e que passei por alguns Problemas e devido a isto, fui forçado a passar todo o código para PDO, o problema e que estou com Dificuldades para substituir dados do Mysqli para PDO no meu Código, ele me apresenta erro nas seguintes linhas: 25, 40, 50, 51, eu tentei fazer as alterações, porem nao obtive exito pelo fato de conhecimento minima, a funcionalidade desta Class e para AltoRouter, caso alguém possa me ajudar. Abaixo Possui meu Codigo!

Class Parser:

```
class Parser
{
    public $get;
    public $post;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->parse_get();
        $this->parse_post();
    }

    public function parse_get($data = false)
    {
        $get   = $_GET;
        $count = 0;
        if ($data) {
            $get = array_merge($get, $data);
        }
        foreach ($get as $key => $value) {
            $this->get->{$key} = $this->sanitize($value);
            $count++;
        }
        $this->get->__total = $count;
        return $this;
    }

    public function parse_post($data = false)
    {
        $post  = $_POST;
        $count = 0;
        if ($data) {
            $post = array_merge($post, $data);
        }
        foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
            $this->post->{$key} = $this->sanitize($value);
            $count++;
        }
        $this->post->__total = $count;
        return $this;
    }

    public function sanitize($value)
    {
        global $db;
        if (is_array($value)) {
            return $value;
        } else {
            if (!$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)) {
                $sanitized = addslashes($db->prepare($value));
                $sanitized->execute();
            } else {
                $sanitized = addslashes($value);
            }
            return $sanitized;
        }
    }
}
```

O Código do AltoRouter esta da seguinte Maneira, Caso Possa me Ajudar com alguma Solução aonde posso eliminar o a Class Parser seria muito bem Vinda!

AltoRouter:

```
require_once 'init.php';

use TOR\Data;
use TOR\Parser;
use TOR\Plugins\AltoRouter;

$glo = new Parser();
$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->setBasePath(Data::BasePath(ADMINPATH));

$router->addRoutes(array(
    array('GET', '/', __DIR__ . '/pages/dashboard.php', 'dashboard'),
));


$match = $router->match();

if ($match) {
    if (is_readable($match["target"])) {
        $glo->parse_get($match["params"]);
        $glo->parse_get(array("param" => $match["name"]));
        require_once $match["target"];
    } else {
        require_once 'pages/add.php';
    }
} else {
    require_once 'pages/add.php';
}
```

Comment: _"ele me apresenta erro nas seguintes linhas: 25, 40, 50, 51"_ que erros? Pode deixar um comentário nas linhas em questão para marcar?

Comment: eu estava analizando, para ver se conseguiria, o maior problema esta na function sanitize, aonde, pois estou tentando fazer com que a função aonde desenvolvi em mysqli transformar em PDO, porem não estou conseguindo